# How to call a function (method) by jquery from jquery dialog open?

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-dialog

I have a jquery dialog opener, and in the open part, I give values for the attributes, and after than I want to call a method. How should I do it? My code:

```
$( "#dialog-form2" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 600,
    width: 1200,
    modal: true,
    title: "Title",
    buttons: {
        "Close": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
    },
    open : function (event, ui) {
        $(this).find('input#my_input_text').val("some text");
        //call a method which is written in the dialog
    }
});
```

//call a method which is written in the dialog - This is where I want to call the method, which is in the opened jsp, not in the same jsp from where I open the dialog.

Thank you!

Comment: Are u talking about calling method within a iframe?

Comment: ohh I am sorry! I didn't think that this is so simple, just to call the method. I am sorry, and thank you!